# How to fill a text input depending on a drop down list selection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a drop down list:

```
<select  class="form-control" name = "Terminal_ID" id = "Terminal_ID" onchange="updateValue();">
<option>Select</option>
<?php
    $query="SELECT *  FROM mytable";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
            $tid=$rows['Idcolumn'];
            $tn=$rows['Namecolumn'];
    ?>  
    <option value="<?=$tn;?>"><?=$tid;?></option> 
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

and a text input box

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="textboxid" name="tname" />
```

I have this on updateValue function in javascript:

```
function updateValue()
    {
$('#textboxid').val($('#Terminal_ID').val());
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
    updateValue();
});
```

It work's, since it shows the value of `$tn` in my text input box. The problem is that, the function change the value of the selection in the dropdown list. and if, i want to use the selection of the drop down to insert some data in my database it sends me the `$tn` value, and i need the `$tid` value. If I change this `<option value="<?=$tn;?>">` to `<option value="<?=$tid;?>">` it change the value of the text input box. Is there anything i can modify to this code to get the `$tn` as value in text input box and the `$tid` as value of the selection?

Comment: None of this questions answer to the mine, since i have to take values from my database and i can't use the text or the value of the drop down list. I have already done that. What i need is to fill the text input box having as condition the selection on the dropdown list. Pleas don't mark it as dublicate

Answer (score 0):

if you set your html `option` like this,

HTML

```
<option value="<?=$tid;?>"><?=$tn;?></option>
```

JS

```
function updateValue()
{
  $('#textboxid').val($('#Terminal_ID option:selected').text()); // this will set name 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    updateValue();
});
```

Comment: this shows all the possible values of the drop down list in my text input box

Comment: how can i get the `tn` value if i don't put it as a value or as a text on the dropdown list?

Comment: @irena see my edit

Comment: if i set my option like that the combo box will have the value of `$tid `but it will show in my page the records of `$tn`.

Answer (score 0):

you can update you function like below that fix your problem

```
    function updateValue()
    {
    $('#textboxid').val($('#Terminal_ID option:selected').text());
    }
```